# deciphering linux encfs (standard config, 192 bit aes) in Java

Tags: java, aes, encryption

Has anyone tried to decipher files encrypted using linux encfs in Java? I'm interested in deciphering the file, and just the file name (not the whole file). I tried:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
//SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithMD5AndAES");
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("asdasd".toCharArray(), new String("Ip/6nf5p4Cvg4uocLdIeHJ7uW/Y=").getBytes(), 162752, 192);
SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
```

I have encfs running with the dafault settings (standard mode, 192 bit aes), and the password should be "asdasd". The config file that encfs generates is:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
>   <!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
>   <boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="7">
>     <config class_id="0" tracking_level="1" version="20" object_id="_0">
> <version>20100713</version>
> <creator>EncFS 1.6</creator>
> <cipherAlg class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
>     <name>ssl/aes</name>
>     <major>2</major>
>     <minor>2</minor>
> </cipherAlg>
> <nameAlg>
>     <name>nameio/block</name>
>     <major>3</major>
>     <minor>0</minor>
> </nameAlg>
> <keySize>192</keySize>
> <blockSize>1024</blockSize>
> <uniqueIV>1</uniqueIV>
> <chainedNameIV>1</chainedNameIV>
> <externalIVChaining>0</externalIVChaining>
> <blockMACBytes>0</blockMACBytes>
> <blockMACRandBytes>0</blockMACRandBytes>
> <allowHoles>1</allowHoles>
> <encodedKeySize>44</encodedKeySize>
> <encodedKeyData>
>     SFGMGDJNNROM/b+sMMlM24DxUsKW80Sen/IFaP849qqqPjy1jP1iiWB8eGB=
> </encodedKeyData>
> <saltLen>20</saltLen>
> <saltData>
>     qjGF2+ngKRPJ2zkx8dMw/Rv0nxg=
> </saltData>
> <kdfIterations>156293</kdfIterations>
> <desiredKDFDuration>500</desiredKDFDuration>
>     </config>
>     </boost_serialization>
> ```

Has anyone tried this before and has the code to show for it?

Answer (score 3):

[This project](https://github.com/mrpdaemon/encfs-java) seems to do exactly what you're talking about. It seems easy enough to use the API:

```
EncFSVolume encFSVolume = new EncFSVolume("<path>", "password");
```

Hope this helps!